# MySQL Database Normalization Advice

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently designing a database for a project I have in college and I would really appreciate some feedback. Basically, the idea of the project is to create a food plants, food inventory database. I have created a schema for the database but I'm not sure if the products table abides by 3NF.

So my products table contains p_id( the primary key), the name of the product, what type is the product (eg pizza or dessert), the country it comes from, the region in that country and who the product is suitable for (eg vegan).

So basically when I break it down, I feel that Region is dependant on Country and type is dependant on the name? Would I be right in assuming this? I could then split the table into 3 separate tables. 1 which would contain p_id, name, Country and another one which would contain Country, Region and a third one which would contain name and type. Would this then be a fully normalised database up to 4NF?

Here is a my schema:

[image]

Comment: `suitable_for` should probably be in another table, since a product may be suitable for more than one type of customer (vegan, kosher, peanut allergies). If you have a comma-separated list, you're violating 1NF.

Comment: Thanks for replying! For suitable_for I'm just going to keep it simple and have only 1 entry so it would be something like this omnivore->Pescetarian->eggetarian->Vegiterian->Vegan. Regarding the other atrbuites in the table do you think it's upto 3NF or 4NF?

Comment: Moving region to a `country_region` table is definitely right. I'm not sure what you're doing with `name` and `type`. Would there be multiple products with the same name? And if there are, wouldn't `suitable_for` be the same for all of them, so that should be in the name-specific table?